# Get Element of XML, which is in another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a class Activity and his XML(1). I need to get a ListView in this activity, which is in another XML(details_items_tasks); in the XML(1) I use  include layout="@layout/details_items_tasks". And when I try to get element I get Null and my app crash.

I need to get thath listView please, healpMe!

Comment: can you share both xml and code where you are using list view ?

Comment: If the XML file is on the file system, it is not local to one activity.  You can grab it whenever you want.  However...  I would suggest using SharedPreferences.  That will handle all your data in an XML format, and you don't need to worry about where it is.

Comment: I use the ListView in the second XML, and in my activity I setContentView with the 1st XML. The 1st I use the comand "include" to call the 2nd XML and my activity I try to findView of the ListView, and I get the null.These files are so big

Comment: Please share the xml layouts

Comment: In the XML 1 , I include a View Flipper int this XML("include). In the layout of View Flipper ("view_flipper.xml"), I include 3 xmls in the ViewFlipper XML ,and one of those I have the listView thaht I want to get.